# Filter by attribute value in Orion Context Broker does not work

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I do not understand why but for some cases filter does not work.
Below is my example:

> /v2/entities?type=carparks&q=name==Parking+Tina+Balice+Krakow&options=keyValues

returns:

```
[
  {
    "id": "15217701",
    "type": "carparks",
    "agglomerations": "1",
    "name": "Parking Tina Balice Krakow"
  }
]
```

The above axample works correctly but second query does not work:

> /v2/entities?type=carparks&q=agglomerations==1

This query returns empty string.

How to filter out this condition:

> type = carparks and agglomerations==1

for this object?

Orion:

> version": "1.2.0"

Comment: Could you edit your question post to include the Orion version you are using, please? Typically, the output of `contextBroker --version`.

Comment: version": "1.2.0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whitespaces in URL query needs to be correctly encoded, either with `+` or `%20`. Have a look [to this document](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

Thus, try the this way

```
/v2/entities?type=carparks&q=name==Parking+Tina+Balice+Krakow&options=keyValues
```

or this other

```
/v2/entities?type=carparks&q=name==Parking%20Tina%20Balice%20Krakow&options=keyValues
```

**EDIT:** regarding

> /v2/entities?type=carparks&q=agglomerations==1

Note that `agglomerations` is an string, while by default equal filter search for numbers (when the value to search is a number, of course). Thus, you have two alternatives:

1. Force to interpret the value as string, using single quotes:

   ```
   /v2/entities?type=carparks&q=agglomerations=='1'
   ```
2. Create/update the entity using numeric values for `agglomerations`. This is the option that probably makes more sense as I understand that the agglomerations semantic is of numeric nature.

Comment: Thanks,  good to know that, but this query works. I have issue with : /v2/entities?type=carparks&q=agglomerations==1, so this is not that case because it does not contain  any whitespace

Comment: If you find useful the answer, please give it a +1 and accept it has valid. This is not to feed my ego :) is to show other users that the answer is valid :) Regarding the problem with `agglomerations==1` please open a new independent SOF question about it in order not to "mix" different questions in the same post. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but my question was: "How to filter out this condition  type = carparks and agglomerations==1?" I did not have any problem with first query, I mentioned it only because I do not understand why for one property it works and for another does not